# I cannot figure out what this question means with the semantic turnstile

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi I have recently started studying propositional logic and am finally understanding the truth tables and how to use them. I came across this formula which is confusing me.

> Use truth tables to establish the following:
>
> (a) $p ∧ q,\, p ⇒ r\models r$.

Is the turnstile the same as $\equiv$ or am i proving that those two formulas are the same as just r?

Comment: Check my answer, the statement is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

$$(p\wedge q),(p\implies r)\models r$$

Means that whenever the formulas $(p\wedge q)$ **and** $(p\implies r)$ are (both simultaneously) true, then $r$ must be true.

So you job is just to write the truth tables of those 3 formulae and verify that in the lines where $[\![(p\wedge q)]\!]=[\![(p\implies r)]\!]=1$, you also have $[\![r]\!]=1$ ($[\![x]\!]$ means the truth value of $x$).

Also, in this case, it's pretty intuitive that this is true, the relevant information of the first formula says that $p$ must be true, the second one says that if $p$ is true then $r$ is true, and we have to conclude that $r$ is true, the 'rule' $(p\wedge q )\models p$ is called conjunction elimination and the rule $p,(p\implies r)\models r$ is called modus ponens.

Answer (score 0):

The turnstile means "show that the thing on the right is true in all valuations for which all things on the left are true".

For example, $\vDash (p=p)$ is a true statement; $\vDash (p=q)$ is not; $(p=q) \vDash (p=q)$ is true.

Comment: so that means the equation I posted is false as r cannot be true on those statements? @Patrick

Comment: @user5647516 No. If $p$ and $q$, and $p \Rightarrow r$, then you have $r$ always, so the equation you posted is true.